# WPF: Image RenderOptions missing in .NET >= 4.0

Tags: .net, wpf, image, render

I created a new WPF project in Visual Studio Community 2015 (tried 2017 as well) targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1.

I used  control to display an image but it was blurry. So I googled and found many answers that the RenderOptions property would resolve the displaying problems.

However, there is no RenderOptions on an Image control in XAML as well as in code behind!

After a couple of hours googling I couldn't find anything that would explain why is that. And then I changed my target version out of curiosity to .NET 3.5 and the RenderOptions is now there! I change it back - the property disappears.

So the question is - why can't I see RenderOptions using newer frameworks. MSDN says that it is available since 3.0 till 4.7.1. But nothing higher than 3.5 works for me.

And if there is no RenderOptions property anymore how can I get my image display in high quality?

Answer (score -1):

I just created a brand new WPF project with VS 2017 targeting 4.7.2.  Here is the super simple XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Image Source="https://placehold.it/500x500" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"  />
</Grid>
```

Does this compile for you?  If it doesn't you likely have an environmental issue.

Comment: Is the `</Window>` close tag missing?